# PLSQL Automation in interactive mode

Tags: shell, plsql, expect

I have a shell  that invokes a .sql file

> **sample.sh**

```
... 
sqlplus /nolog @sample.sql 

....
```

> **sample.sql**

```
....
accept selection Prompt "Enter username"
...
```

I need to automate the execution of the script from the shell script. 
How do i make automate the data entry through the shell script.

I have tried the following

**Pass Parameters to SQL**

```
   sqlplus /nolog @sample.sql <<EOF
    abc
    EOF
```

**using expect**

```
/usr/bin/expect  <<EOD 2>&1
set timeout 60
 expect {
 "Enter username "{
  send "abc\r"
 }}
expect eof
```

**Note**: i am not passing parameters to the script. The script prompts for information, and the user needs to enter it on the fly.

Found the solution, have mentioned it below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

Okay, I found the answer it was pretty simple

```
 sqlplus / as sysdba @sample.sql <<EOF
    abc
    EOF
```

The problem was that i was not logging in as current user.

As soon as the scripts prompts:

```
Enter username:
```

Automatically "abc"  gets entered.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use as this:

```
sample.sh

var1="somevalues"
...
sqlplus -s user/pass@host <<EOF
@sample.sql $var1
EOF
...

sample.sql

select &1 from table;
```

You can pass the values from Unix tp SQL in such manner.

Comment: I am not passing values... it is in interactive mode... the user has to enter data

Comment: your question clearly says "How do i make automate the data entry through the shell script.". Better to rewrite your question so it is clear about what you are trying to accomplish. Good luck.

Comment: You can put the sqlplus call code in loop along with read command to read values through console in unix and then pass the value. Hope this helps.

Comment: @ManishV, okay, that was exactly what me question was how to do it? because i know i know of expect and that is int working